# AI - String/Text Classification/Categorization (e.g. a string/text is classified as a company name)

Tags: string, nlp, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, classification

My problem is to filter out all the names of persons in a table, i.e. names of companies, schools, institutions will be left in the database.

I tried a simple solution wherein I was given a list of the name of companies, schools, etc. And I searched for the most common terms there. (Note: I did not search for the common strings in a name, since that would cost a lot). I assigned weight to those terms, and also to the most common substrings. With that, if the string has a corp, inc, school, univ in it then it's very highly possible that it's not a name of a person.

Now, my problem is how can I make it into an AI. Moreover, I will have to make it possible such that classifications of companies only, schools only, etc. will be easier.

For example

```
XYZ Brewery Corporation -> company
Harvard University -> school
Department of Health -> government agency
```

The only AI techniques I know are Naive-Bayes, K-Means, Hierarchical, FCM, ANN. Those techniques commonly get numerical values, so, I don't know how to make it into an AI. The only AI techniques that I know that handles strings extensively are Levenshtein, Stemming, Needleman-Wunch and Jaro-Winkler.

Is my first approach incorrect? How can incorporate the techniques that I know? Do I have to learn a new technique? I'm basically new to AI since I am still a student. However, this is not an assignment but it's for a company project (actually I am the only computer science major in our group, so it's very heavy on my part). By the way, if you are curious on what language I use, I am using C# since I am planning to make it just a stand-alone application and the users are using Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just jump into fancy machine learning algorithms. Your common sense and intuition can get you quite far.
Your idea of having large lists of entities is pretty good, and might work out very well for schools, if you can find a list of all the post-secondary institutions in the world. If you can compile together such a list, its unlikely it will contain **every** university in the world, but it will probably be good enough for all practical purposes.
From the lists you have already compiled, you can count the number of times every unigram (i.e. word) and bigram (i.e. consecutive pairs of words) occurs for each class of entities and see certain phrases strongly tend towards a particular class (e.g. 'department of' might mostly occur for government agencies, 'inc', 'ltd', '& co.' might occur only for companies, 'university', 'school', 'college' might occur mostly for schools). You can formalize these ideas into a Naive Bayes model, but having a simpler rule that just checks for certain phrases in a a large if-then statement might get you 90% of the way there.

Comment: It's a good point that he already knows these strings are the names of some type of entity, and so full-on NER is actually somewhat irrelevant. In that case, heuristics like this (or some kind of simple Naive Bayes / decision tree model) will probably do fine -- maybe augmented by doing a Wikipedia lookup and seeing what categories it falls under in cases where you're not sure, if that's feasible.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so what i've been doing is just using unigrams and substring of it. so what's better to use NER or this one, if you are considering the accuracy and the number of entities retrieved vs the total actual number? because our client want to have the number of retrieved data as close as possible to the actual total amount

Comment: A NER system will help you locate such phrases in a piece of text (and possibly label them with one these labels as well). The problem you have given us about classifying strings that are already known to be names of some type of entity into a specific type of entity. The problem you have specified is much simpler and so you can probably do something much simpler than an NER system to solve it.

Comment: +1 to Dougal's wikipedia idea.. Systematic scraping of wikipedia could help you collect very large lists of each kind of entity.

Comment: Re-reading your question, you are specifically looking for person names v/s non-person names. You can compile large lists of common first and last names and lookup those as well. Google for 'precision and recall' and understand what those terms mean and try to understand which one is more important for your given task and how that impacts your final algorithm.

Comment: ok. so, it's bayesian classifier then. actually at first I didn't get Dougal's comment about wikipedia but I understand it now. that will really give me a huge amount of data and lessen the time.

Comment: actually, it's not only about person name vs. non-person names. because i've already made an algorithm using the most common uniwords and substrings to filter out those person names. and then the client said to classify also those non-person names. so, i need to identify those non-person names into another kind of classification

Comment: I agree with adi92's suggestion that do not jump into ML solutions too quickly. One technique I used is to build a simple Naive Bayes program to calculate the probability of each P(category|word), then going through the high-probability words, manually identify the ones that make sense for simple text match. As building a high-accuracy ML model is going to take considerable higher effort to fine-tune your parameters, and is really difficult to debug unexpected result.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is generally called [Named Entity Recognition (NER)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition). The [SharpNLP project](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/) is a C# library of NLP algorithms, including NER. It seems to be completely undocumented, though it's a C# port of Apache's OpenNLP, which has [documentation on name finding](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind); SharpNLP's interface is presumably similar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Febrl project.

> [Febrl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/febrl/) (Freely Extensible Biomedical Record Linkage) does data
>   standardisation (segmentation and cleaning) and probabilistic record
>   linkage ("fuzzy" matching) of one or more files or data sources which
>   do not share a unique record key or identifier.

In particular take a look at the file named *biomed2002hmm.pdf* int the doc archive. It discusses the use of lexical tokenization and Hidden Markov Models to identify patterns for names and addresses.

The ideas presented could be applied to your problem of identifying personal versus business names. The project includes code examples (in Python though, not C#) of the techniques described.

Answer (score 0):

The python library [probablepeople](https://github.com/datamade/probablepeople) use a conditional random field model to do this. (I'm an contributor to this project),